# Is it possible to create an exit hook in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I have a connection to a device. Whenever my app shuts down or the connection to the device is lost, I want to update a collection to set it to a state.

```
function onExit() {
  Cylon.observer.stop();
  Cylon.connections.update({}, {
    $set: { homed: false }
  });
}
Meteor.beforeExit(onExit);
Cylon.devices.on('disconnect', onExit);
```

Would there be a way to create exit hooks in Meteor?

Answer (score 4):

Meteor application is still an Node.js application, you might consider to use one of the following event listener to do the data update before your application exit

```
process.on('exit', function() {...})
process.on('uncaughtException', function() {...}}
```

Comment: It seems like none of the above events are fired when a meteor program shuts down.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this package [mizzao:user-status](https://atmospherejs.com/mizzao/user-status) to track the users status and observe your users, for example :

[image]

```
Meteor.users.find({ "status.online": true }).observe({
  added: function(id) {
    // id just came online
  },
  removed: function(id) {
    // id just went offline
  }
});
```

Comment: not totally what I was looking for -- not a log out hook, but when the app completely stops